# Git(git) not found in terminal

Tags: android, git, kivy, buildozer

I downloaded the pydroid 3 app from google play on my samsung tablet. Its amazing. Kivy works beautifully. After setting my spec file, I try to use buildozer, I get a git not found error. I am trying to build a sample android app to make sure the kivy-buildozer setup is complete. I installed gitpython, it didnt help. Thank You

```
$ cd /storage/emulated/0/sm    
/storage/emulated/0/sm 
$ buildozer -v android debug 
 Check configuration tokens
 Ensure build layout
 Check configuration tokens
 Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
 Preparing build
 Check requirements for android
 Run 'dpkg --version'
 Cwd None
/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/sh: dpkg: not found
 Search for Git (git)
 Git (git) not found, please install it.
 /storage/emulated/0/sm $ pip install git
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement git (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for git
```

Comment: check if you have installed the plugin named git. you can check it by going to settings, plugin, and check if you have git enabled in the downloaded plugins.

Comment: Hi, I dont see that option in my settings anywhere.

Comment: The hard part here will be getting an android sdk/ndk that runs on Android. This is likely to be hard, unless pydroid happens to support it.

Comment: Inclement you are correct. Unfortunate: Developer response:
Buildozer requires Android SDK that is unavailable on Android. So it won't work independently of git availability.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the app developer:

Developer response:
Buildozer requires Android SDK that is unavailable on Android. So it won't work independently of git availability.